# Find a string and add multiple lined string saved in variable before

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have been trying quite a few ways with no luck.  I have a file named test.txt that has some lorem ipsum and the text [staging: production] I simply want to add a few lines that I have saved in a variable in before it.

If you could explain where I have gone wrong with any of the below it would be much appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

test="lala\
kjdsh"

sed '/^#$/{N; /[staging: production]/ i \
<Location /cgis> \
</Location>\

}' ./test.txt


sed -i -e 's/\[staging\: production\]/\$test/g' ./test.txt
#sed -i 's/Lorem/beautiful/g' test.txt

#awk -v data=$test '{A[NR]=$0}/\[staging\: production\]/{ print data }' test.txt > testfile.txt

#read -a text <<<$(cat test.txt)
#echo ${#text[@]}
#for i in ${text[@]};
#do
#   echo -n $i;
#   sleep .2;
#done

#ed -s test.txt <<< $'/\[staging\: production\]/s/lalalala/g\nw'

#awk -v data=$test '/\(/\[staging\: production\]\)/ { print data }' test.txt > testfile.txt

# && mv testfile.txt test.txt

#sed -i -e '/\(\[staging\: production\]\)/r/$test\1/g' test.txt

#sed "/\(\[staging\: production\]\)/s//$test\1/g" test.txt
```

Comment: When you use a backslash as a line continuation character, the lines are joined as if there's no newline. Remove the backslash and the newlines will be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/\[staging\: production\]/\$test/g' ./test.txt
```

won't work because inside singe quotes BASH will not expand `\$test`.
Therefore you don't need to escape the `$`.

If you want to substitute with the contents of the variable `$test` do:

```
sed -i -e 's/\[staging: production\]/'$test'/g' ./test.txt
```

You also do not need to escape `:`

To insert before your pattern works for me this way:

```
sed -i -e '/\[staging: production\]/ i '$test'' ./test.txt
```

However to preserve the linebreak inside the variable I needed to define:

```
test="lala\nkjdsh"
```

Please note the `\n` to encode the linebreak.

Comment: That appears to be working, however, it is not preserving the new lines in my variable.

Comment: I keep getting sed: 1: "/\[staging: production\ ...": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: well as I said - I had to encode the linebreaks inside the variable via `\n` - that did preserve the linebreaks in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in perl, it seems to work fine:

```
perl -pe '{$rep="what\nnow"; s/(\[foo foo2\])/$rep$1/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
test="lala\\                                   
kjdsh"
sed '/\[staging: production\]/i\'"$test" test.txt
```

N.B. `\\` in the variable and the variable is surrouded by `"`'s in the sed command.